# Linq query of left outer join not properly working

Tags: c#, sql, linq, filtering, sql-to-linq-conversion

I converted **sql** query to **linq** query without any **error**.

Now, my question is that I get the data properly in sql query, while in linq query showing the whole data without filtering **product null**.

Here is my code:

**SQL Query**

```
SELECT Name
FROM ProductMaster product
LEFT JOIN TouchWastageGroup touchWastageGroup ON touchWastageGroup.Product = product.Name and touchWastageGroup.GroupNameId = 2 and touchWastageGroup.CaratId = 6
WHERE touchWastageGroup.Product IS NULL
```

From this query data showing properly.

**Linq Query**

```
var productSelected = (from product in _productMasterRepository.Table
from touchWastageGroup in _touchWastageGroupRepository.Table
.Where(touchWastageGroup => touchWastageGroup.Product == product.Name && touchWastageGroup.GroupNameId == 2 && touchWastageGroup.CaratId == 6)                                   
.DefaultIfEmpty().Where(x => x.Product == null)
select new
{
   Result = product.Name
}).ToList();
```

Same query of linq showing whole data without filtering this (**Where(x => x.Product == null)**).

Is there a problem in linq syntax or in query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check with following query to return which has no product

```
from product in _productMasterRepository.Table
join touchWastageGroup in _touchWastageGroupRepository.Table on new { Product = product.Product, GroupNameId = 2, CaratId = 6 } equals new { touchWastageGroup.Product, touchWastageGroup.GroupNameId, touchWastageGroup.CaratId } into joinedResult
from touchWastageGroup in joinedResult.DefaultIfEmpty()
where touchWastageGroup == null
select new { Result = product.Name }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this query

```
var productSelected = from product in _productMasterRepository.Table
join from touchWastageGroup in _touchWastageGroupRepository.Table on
product.Name equals touchWastageGroup.Product into temp
from t in temp.DefaultIfEmpty()
where t.GroupNameId == 2 && t.CaratId == 6
select new
{
   Result = product.Name
}).ToList();
```